# Trying to interpret (VS2008) Threads Window with whats actually executing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm new to multi-threading and I have been doing a Proof-of-Concept, I've also 'discovered' the (VS2008) Threads Window: 
[image]

**My Question is**: how can I "link" the running threads to my code?
For example, how would I get the Thread ID (as shown in the Threads Window) so that I could log it (for example); **or**, the BeginInvoke() method takes a 'id' argument (string) which I have set (as "Service A" in the example below) but I can't see it in the Threads Window.

The thing that interests me is that I'm sparking up **three** parallel threads of execution using AsyncCallbacks and BeginInvoke() but I can only see two worker threads in the Threads Window at a point where i think I should see three.  Actually I think I can - the three worker threads with the 'Name' as `<No Name>`.

For reference here's some of the code I'm using:

```
// Creating the call back and setting the call back delegate
AsyncCallback callBackA = new AsyncCallback(AsyncOperationACompleted);
// callBackB ...
// callBackC ...

// Create instances of the delegate, which calls the method we want to execute
callerA = new DumbEndPoint.AsyncMethodCaller(DumbEndPoint.PretendWorkingServiceCall);
// callerB ...
// callerC ...

// sleep = thread sleep time in milliseconds
IAsyncResult resultA = callerA.BeginInvoke(sleep, "Service A", callBackA, null);
// resultB ...
// resultC ...

// I expect to see three threads in the Threads Window at this point.
```

I'm then getting the results in the call back delegate:

```
    private void AsyncOperationACompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {               
            string returnValue = callerA.EndInvoke(result);
            mySmartDTO.ServiceDataA = returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logging
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Thread.Name to set a name for the thread.  After the name is set, it will appear in the "Name" column of the Threads window.

e.g., assuming that `Service A` is the name you'd like to appear in the Name column of the Threads window, you could do something like this in `PretendWorkingServiceCall`:

```
void PretendWorkingServiceCall(int sleepMilliseconds, string name)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = name;

    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yeah - I'm bit of a moron.  I just realised that after playing around some more :)  One thing though, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns a completely different id.

Comment: @Adrian K: For the unmanaged thread ID (which is what you see in the Threads window), see `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` .  However, there can potentially be scenarios where managed thread IDs are not one-to-one with unmanaged thread IDs.  The documentation and compiler warning you'll get if you use this method explain the details a bit further.